# How to determine if window.confirm() is supported?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a mobile website that is used by various devices including some onboard computers running a locked down version of Windows Embedded 7 with IE 7. For some reason that I cannot explain, `window.confirm()` is broken, yet all other javascript seems to work.

I even added the following check before wiring up the confirm handler, but clicking the link simply does nothing.

```
        if (window.confirm)
        {
            $(".logoff").click(function () 
            {
                return confirm("Are you sure you want to log off?");
            });
        }
```

If I remove the click handler, the link functions as normal. Is there a better way to test for `confirm()` support?

Comment: Why not use a custom implementation? Of course it could not return the selection without blocking the browser in a nasty way, but you could easily do it with a callback.

Comment: @ThiefMaster are you suggesting a modal dialog?

Comment: Yes, exactly [stupid minimum length]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the following suggested methods worked in every desktop browser I tested, they all evaluated to true on the device and still didn't display a dialog or navigate to the link in the anchor's href.

```
if (typeof confirm == 'object')
if ('confirm' in window && typeof window.confirm === 'object')
if (window.confirm)
```

(In IE 7, `typeof somefunction` is `'object'` instead of `'function'`)

My solution was to use a [jQuery UI Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) instead, based on @ThiefMaster's suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
if ('confirm' in window) {
    $(".logoff").click(function () {
        return window.confirm("Are you sure you want to log off?");
    });
}
```

Another options would be `window.hasOwnProperty('confirm')`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use **typeof** to check if the window.confirm is a function

Answer (score 1):

You could do

```
if ('confirm' in window && typeof window.confirm === 'function' ) {
    $(".logoff").click(function () {
        return window.confirm("Are you sure you want to log off?");
    });
}
```

Comment: window.hasOwnProperty('confirm') returns false.

Comment: @kennebec yes it's true, i don't know why. I modified my answer to use in

Comment: It seems that `typeof window.confirm` is "object" in IE 7 and 8, but "function" in 9.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(typeof confirm=='function')// window.confirm is defined and a function
```